# Using trigonometric formulas to prove that $m_1m_2$ = -1 for perpendicular lines?

Tags: trigonometry, alternative-proof

How do you use trigonometric formulas (or identities) to prove that the product of the gradients of two perpendicular lines is -1?

If
$y = m_1x + c_1 \text{ and } y = m_2x + c_2,$

I thought finding an angle would help to incorporate one of the identities, and hence get somewhere. But how do I find an angle? Constructing two vectors in terms of the y-intercepts and x-intercepts of the two equations like below?

($y_1$ is the *y*-intercept of the first equation, $x_1$ is the *x*-intercept of the first equation, and so on.)

$
\rightarrow \left(\begin{array}{c}x_1\\ y_1\end{array}\right) \text{•} 
\left (\begin{array}{c}x_2\\ y_2\end{array}\right) \\~\\
\rightarrow \left(\sqrt{(x_1^2 + y_1^2)(x_2^2 + y_2^2)}\hspace{0.08cm} \right) \cos \theta = x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 \\
\theta = \cos^{{-}1} \left[\frac{x_1x_2 + y_1y_2}{\sqrt{(x_1^2 + y_1^2)(x_2^2 + y_2^2)}} \right]
$

But this is taking me nowhere!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you know vectors, you can recall that the lines have direction vectors $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ m_1\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}1\\ m_2\end{pmatrix}$ respectively. Then note that the lines are perpendicular if and only if their directions vectors are perpendicular (i.e. their dot product is $0$). This will get you the result.

Comment: Minus One-Twelfth.Right your comment as an snsert , I delete mine.OK?

Answer (score 5):

If $\theta$ is the angle made by the first line with $x-$ axis then the slope of this line is $\tan (\theta)$. The slope of the second line is $\tan (\pi /2+\theta)=-\cot(\theta)$. Since $\tan (\theta)$ $(-\cot (\theta))=-1$ we are done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sir.